# ListActivity force closes

Tags: android, listactivity, forceclose

Whenever a button opens up the About class, the app just force closes. I've followed a video tutorial exactly, so it shouldn't be any errors.

So I basically want to have a list that have three items in it. And then when you click on of them, it will take you to the specific activity. So is there anything missing? I know I haven't set any onClickListeners, but I just want this list to work properly before I continue.

Here's the java file:

```
package com.heavyfork.sq;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class About extends ListActivity {

protected String[] aboutList = {
        "More Apps",
        "About",
        "Help"

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, aboutList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.about, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".About" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/aboutList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

LogCat:

```
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.heavyfork.sq/com.heavyfork.sq.About}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2312)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1250)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5229)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:273)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1889)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at com.heavyfork.sq.About.onCreate(About.java:27)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5154)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
05-09 18:01:27.936: E/AndroidRuntime(16943):    ... 11 more
```

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1):

If you use a list activity you need to have an item with

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

So change your list's id from

```
    android:id="@+id/aboutList"
```

into the layout xml

Answer (score 1):

Your activity is derived from `ListActivity` that requires your layout to contain an id called `list`, so you have to define it this way:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

As said this is due to the implementation of `ListView` that offers some convenience methods for lists.

Cheers